# How to use a method in the same class in another method, which requires a different parameter

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to minimize the amount of code needed to click a button, but because I have a picture on each button, if the user clicks the image then it also needs to go to the appropriate page. Is there a way in which I can call the same method from the non-image button (which is an ActionEvent and the image has a parameter of MouseEvent)

I tried fixing the error using the IDE's option to create a method for this, but it didn't seem to do anything.

```
    @FXML
    private void clickedNewPlayer(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("New or Edit Player Screen.fxml"));
            Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in opening window" + e);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void clickedNewPlayerImage(MouseEvent event) {
        try {
            ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("New or Edit Player Screen.fxml"));
            Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in opening window" + e);
        }
    }
```

Nothing wrong with the output, I'm just trying to minimize on the code, as I have 6 buttons, all with this same problem

Comment: Is there a common interface between `MouseEvent` and `ActionEvent`?

Comment: You don't need the `clickedNewPlayerImage` method at all. If you click on the image on the button it should still fire an ActionEvent.

Comment: Yes, there is a common interface between the `MouseEvent` and `ActionEvent`. Jurgen, when I click the image nothing happens, but if I click around the edges of the image (i.e. on the button), then only does it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All JavaFX events are descendant from `javafx.event.Event`; this  is where the `getSource()` method comes from<sup>1</sup>. As the source of the event appears to be the only thing you need from the parameter, you could simply have one method whose single parameter type is `Event`. Then configure `onAction` and `onMouseClicked` to use that method in your FXML file.

Another option is to have a third method that handles showing your "new or edit player" dialog. Then you'd simply have your event-handler methods call that third method.

---

<sup>1. The `getSource()` method actually comes from `java.util.EventObject`, which `Event` extends. But as we're using JavaFX, `Event` should be considered the top of the hierarchy.</sup>

Comment: This helped a lot because I'm new to this, Thank you